# Can the date command take as argument another date command in a file?

Tags: date

I am reading through the [GNU coreutils manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual),
and I am experimenting with the `date` command. 
Here is what I found in the text:

1. The `date` command has a `-f datefile` option:

   - Parse each line in *datefile* as with `-d`
     and display the resulting date and time.
   - that means `date` is looking at each line in *datefile*
     and treating it as a date string for use to display a particular date.
2. In [chapter 29 (Date input formats)](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html), it is stated:

   > The output of the `date` command
   > is not always acceptable as a date string,
   > not only because of the language problem, but also because
   > there is no standard meaning for time zone items like ‘IST’. 
   > **When using `date` to generate a date string
   > intended to be parsed later**,
   > specify a date format that is independent of language
   > and that does not use time zone items other than ‘UTC’ and ‘Z’. 
   > Here are some ways to do this:
   >
   > ```
   > $ LC_ALL=C TZ=UTC0 date
   >              ︙
   > ```

   - this statement (especially the bold part) implies to me
     that I should be able to put in the *datefile* a `date` command
     such as the one above,
     and the `date` command I issue in the terminal
     should be able to parse that `date` command in the *datefile*
     and output the corresponding date.

It is not working for me. 
Either there is something wrong with my date command in the datefile
(wrong quotation marks,
some special syntax which I am not aware of...),
or the `-f datefile` option is not capable of handling this situation.

What I am asking, in summary, is:

- can the `date -f` command be fed a file
  where the date string on one line is another date command? 
  e.g., can I put in a file a string "date" on the first line
  (which, as a command, would return the system time),
  and then feed that file into a `date -f` command
  and get the current system time
  (generated by the `date` command in the file)?

Comment: What does your date command look like, and what does the file look like? In other words, please post your exact input and command(s).

Comment: The key bit you're missing re: the bolded bit, is that's when using `date` to *generate* a date.  So you can use `LC_ALL=C TZ=UTC0 date ...` to *generate* the string that you then put in the file you're going to parse with `date -f datefile`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct format for a date-time that will be correctly parsed by GNU date is:

```
$ LC_ALL=C TZ=UTC0 date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"
2016-09-28T04:08:55+0000
```

And that avoids spaces also, which may generate other problems.

If your file contains one line per date like:

```
$ cat dates.txt
1992-03-28T14:26:01+0000
2004-02-29T21:02:02+0000
2005-02-28T21:02:03+0000
2015-07-02T11:52:04+0000
2016-03-31T01:36:05+0000
```

Then this will work:

```
$ TZ=America/Los_Angeles date -f infile
Sat Mar 28 06:26:01 PST 1992
Sun Feb 29 13:02:02 PST 2004
Mon Feb 28 13:02:03 PST 2005
Thu Jul  2 04:52:04 PDT 2015
Wed Mar 30 18:36:05 PDT 2016
```

---

---

If what you want to do is create a file with "date commands" as in:

```
$ cat dates.txt
date -d "1992-03-28T14:26:01+0000"
date -d "2004-02-29T21:02:02+0000"
LC_ALL=C TZ=UTC0 date -d "2005-02-28T21:02:03+0000" +"%Y-%m-%d"
TZ=America/Los_Angeles date -d "2005-02-28T21:02:03+0000"
date -d "2015-07-02T11:52:04+0000"
date -d "2016-03-31T01:36:05+0000"
```

Then you need to execute each line with the shell.
One fast solution is to source the file and all commands will be excuted.

```
$ . ./dates.txt
Sat Mar 28 14:26:01 GMT 1992
Sun Feb 29 21:02:02 GMT 2004
2005-02-28
Mon Feb 28 13:02:03 PST 2005
Thu Jul  2 11:52:04 GMT 2015
Thu Mar 31 01:36:05 GMT 2016
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Many thanks guys for your interest in my question and for the support you are trying to provide. However, I must say, with all due respect, that you are missing the point of my question: all your posts place a valid date string (generated by a date command) in a file and then use the date -f command. However, that is not what I am asking. What I am asking is: can the date -f command be fed a file where the date string on one line is another date command?

Comment: e.g. can I put in a file a string "date" on the first line (which as a command would return the system time), and then feed that file in a date -f command and get the current system time (generated by the date command in the file)?

Comment: @AndreiCostache For your first question the answer is No. The date command could not interpret another date command. You need the shell to execute commands, not date. You can however source a file that has a list of date commands. I'll write that up. Please modify your question to explain this requirement.

Comment: I modified the question with a copy paste of my additional explanations which were much better understood. I would recommend that in your definitive answer, you mention also that the date **-d** command is in fact capable of this. (see chapter 21.1.6 in the GNU Coreutils manual where there is a specific example for this). This way there is less chance for confusion (I think);

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not read `LC_ALL=C TZ=UTC0` from a file with `date -f`.

```
cat tz
LC_ALL=C TZ=UTC0

date -f tz
date: invalid date ”LC_ALL=C TZ=UTC0”
```

You can, however, put the entire command in a file, like this:

```
cat date
#!/bin/bash

LC_ALL=C TZ=UTC0 date
```

Then run it from the command line, which gives you:

```
./date 
Tue Sep 27 06:56:29 UTC 2016
```

As opposed to the timezone on my server which is:

```
date
tis 27 sep 2016 08:56:52 CEST
```

Comment: your first example has no chance to work, because you are writing in the file only the locale/timezone modifiers of the date command but not the date command itself; the _date -f tz_ command will try to recognize a date in the string "LC_ALL=C TZ=UTC0", which fails...

Comment: your second example I can follow, but it does not answer my question whether date is in fact capable of this feature or not. I will keep messing with it and post back if I find anything.

Answer (score 0):

With `date` from coreutils 8.21, TZ=UTC and LC_ALL=C I get

```
$ date > x; sleep 1; date >> x; sleep 1; date >> x
$ date -f x
Wed Sep 28 03:32:39 UTC 2016
Wed Sep 28 03:32:40 UTC 2016
Wed Sep 28 03:32:41 UTC 2016
$
```

as expected.  I checked the source code, too: The magic happens in the routine `batch_convert` where essentially there's a loop over `parse_datetime()`/`show_date()` just as in the command line case (using `-d`).